# Do something before window configuration change

Tags: window, hooks

AFAIK, `window-configuration-change-hook` applies *after* a configuration change, and there is no corresponding `window-before-configuration-change-hook`.

What's the best way to detect window configuration change *before* the change occurs?

**Edit**: use case:

[`centered-window-mode`](https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode) centers the window by hacking fringe widths. This can sometimes [make the window too small to split](https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode/issues/12). Ideally, we can detect window configuration changes like splitting and reset fringes to previous values to prevent such errors.

Comment: There is nothing for that purpose so far as I'm aware. What are you trying to do?

Comment: [`centered-window-mode`](https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode) centers the window by hacking fringe widths. This can sometimes [make the window too small to split](https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode/issues/12). Ideally, we can detect window configuration changes like splitting and reset fringes to previous values to prevent such errors.

Comment: What @phils said. (Please add the use case to the question itself, as comments can be deleted at any time.) In your context, what happens if you (as a workaround) try it once and if unsuccessful then reset fringes and try it again?

Comment: That would involve advising the `split-window` fn, wouldn't it? Packages probably shouldn't advise fns.